# Display Ruler Information in less (cursor position)

Tags: linux, less, ruler

Sometimes, if I know I'm not going to do any edits in a window, I use less instead of vi. However, vi displays percentage and cursor position in the bottom right corner. Is there a way to mimic this behavior when using less?

PS - I'm 98% that I could see this ruler-type information at my last job, but maybe they were using an older version or an alias?

I tried to find the information in these locations: 
 [vi set ruler](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3073/what-is-a-vi-equivalent-of-vims-set-ruler-command) and [line numbers in less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831681/how-to-display-line-numbers-in-less-gnu)

Comment: I know that I could, in theory, use vi -R, but that's not the question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reach out to an old coworker and get their less alias.

less -M

From the man-page:

> -m or --long-prompt 
>  Causes less to prompt verbosely (like more), with the percent into the file.  By default, less prompts with a  colon. 
>  
>  -M or --LONG-PROMPT 
>  Causes less to prompt even more verbosely than more.

This experience has made me think that vi might be better for most things...